# How to get status of employees according to updates with the dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one table as empl with records as

```
EMPID   SDATE       SAL     DESIGNATION
=======================================
1001    21-SEP-17   55000   Technology Analyst
1002    22-SEP-19   52000   Technology Analyst
1003    15-SEP-17   65000   Technology Lead
1004    21-SEP-15   72000   Technology Lead
1005    11-MAR-20   55000   SSE
1006    22-JAN-20   55000   SSE
```

We need to update the startDate with the next Date (as sysdate or 1 week later) for all the employees, batches wise (designation wise) in PLSQL keeping in mind the performance.
while updating --> log records in some any table (**emp_log**) with the Updation status like below if updation got succeeded for particular employee then status would be **Success** & if updation got failed for some employees then status would be **Failed**.

```
empid   Update_Status
=====================
1001     Success
1002     Failed
1003     Success
.....
```

What would be PL/SQL block statement to get this type of status with **empid**?

Comment: What results do you want?  It is not clear what you want to update.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my question. could you please see the question again.

Comment: Keeping in mind the performance - if you want to update all employees you just do 

update empl set sdate = <your_expression>;

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski Thanks Marcin, but what about status update in another table. This statement should run in PLSQL block. Any idea about update status in table.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please post what you have tried and where you think what is the problem.

Comment: @MdWasi If you run the update on the whole table, and it succeeds, then you can assume that the update status = Success for all employees.  If the update fails, you can assume that the update status = Failed for all employees. If you really need this "log" then you can run insert into emp_log (empid, update_status) select empid, 'Success' from empl; after the update. What are you trying to achieve really? What have you tried?

Comment: @MdWasi you have to use `bulk collect` in `PL/SQL record` type. Fetch employees details in batch wise (eg: 10000 at one time) then update into another table & then if record updated successfully status would be success else it got failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your real use case to update the date only I don't see any error which will occur until you have any such constraints on it or any trigger validations.

However if this is just an example and you have bigger logic in mind then I would provide below code with comments from my side which might give you a sight to proceed.

Because you talk about performance I would use collection like `bulk collect` and `forall` with `limit` catching the DML errors using `save exceptions`

```
declare
  -- cursor to fetch the data which we want to update
  -- additional wherr clauses can be added as per need
  cursor cur_emp 
  is
  select *
    from emp;
  -- rowtype variablr to hold the record
  -- we can also use emp%rowtype
  type emp_tab is table of cur_emp%rowtype;
  -- local variable for the table type above
  l_emp_data emp_tab;
  -- user defined exception to catch bulk exception error
  dml_errors exception;
  -- actual ORA error number map to dml_errors
  pragma exception_init(dml_errors, -24381);
  -- othet local variables for convenience purpose
  l_errors number;
  l_errno  number;
  l_msg    varchar2(4000);
  l_idx    number;
begin
  open cur_emp;
  loop
    -- using limit as 100 which is recommended when we use bulk collect
    fetch cur_emp bulk collect 
    into l_emp_data limit 100;
    begin
      -- updating 100 records at one shot 
      -- saving exception per record in case of failure
      forall i in 1 .. l_emp_data.count 
      save exceptions
      update emp
         set sdate = sysdate
       where empid = l_emp_data(i).empid;
      -- we can insert all records as successful intially
      -- which further in the exception section will be updated in case of any dml error
      forall i in 1 .. l_emp_data.count
      insert into emp_log
      values(l_emp_data(i).empid,'Success',null);
    exception
      -- handling the user defined exception 
      -- and updating erroneous records
      when dml_errors then
        l_errors := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;
        for i in 1 .. l_errors
        loop
          l_errno := sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code;
          l_msg   := sqlerrm(-l_errno);
          l_idx   := sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index;
          -- i added additional error message as well
          update emp_log
             set status  = 'Failed'
                ,err_msg = l_errno||'-'||l_msg
           where empid = l_emp_data(l_idx).empid;
        end loop;
    end;
    exit when cur_emp%notfound;
  end loop;
  close cur_emp;
end;
/
```

However I feel if you only want to update the dates per `designation` in batch then a simple update is enough and as as each employee is uniquely identified I don't see any performance issue even though you have 10000 records per designation.(you can give it a try if you think so)

At end I also would like to tell about leveraging `dml error logging` which is available since 10g which you can find [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2). You will have a system generated table which will log all the erroneous records during a DML operation out of which you can create a view to see success or failure as per your need.

I am also providing the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2154449277ef3fe362f2f967de351757) for your reference which has the execution result of above code. I have not simulated the error part which I  leave it to you.